# c# return generic function as a result of another function

Tags: c#

I want to return generic function as a result of my function in C#.

For example, I want to create a function `PopManyBuilder(int n)` which returns a function that will take any `List` and return copy of the given `List`, but without n last elements.

I tried something like this:

```
static Func<List<T>, List<T>> PopManyBuilder<T>(int n)
{
    return list =>
    {
        var result = new List<T>(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
        }

        return result;
    };
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pop5 = PopManyBuilder<int>(5);
    var array = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    var newArray = pop5.Invoke(b);
}
```

But I can't use built function `pop5` on any `List<T>`, only on `List<int>`.

How can I create a function `pop5` for all possible types?

Comment: You are, already doing it, PopManyBuilder Is generic and could be string,double etc without limit. So I dont understand what you really want.

Comment: @Alen.Toma I want to make a type independent function, not only for String, Double, Int or any specified type.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @zahrakhani for example for `List<Double>` https://imgur.com/a/jm7bH36

Comment: @IaroslavSviridov this is because you passed `int` to `PopManyBuilder`.

Comment: @IaroslavSviridov Tried to post but your question was closed. The problem is, in `PopManyBuilder` you are modifying the original list, not the copy you called `result`. When it returns, you get the original list. Solution is to update `result` in the loop e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { result.RemoveAt(result.Count - 1); }`. That should work with float, etc. For instance `var pop5 = PopManyBuilder<float>(5); var array = new List<float> { 1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f, 8f }; var newArray = pop5.Invoke(array);`

Comment: @derloopkat Yeah, you are right, but how to create type independent function like this? When we want to remove an element from an `List` , we don't care what type of element it is.

Comment: You could get type from the input list. However this question is closed.

Comment: @derloopkat Post a link to something working on dotnetfiddle.net -- what the OP wants isn't possible, per the linked question. So if you can make it work, I'll vote to re-open